# Custom rule that says there can be no project versions or dependency versions that begin with the string "master-"

Tags: java, maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am creating a custom rule by following the [writing-a-custom-rule](https://maven.apache.org/components/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html).

The intent is to use [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) to accomplish the following objective:

> "Writing a custom rule that says there can be no project versions or
>   dependency versions that begin with the string 'master-'".

So I have the following java class-

```
package com.gridpoint.energy.customRule;


import org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver;
import org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRule;
import org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRuleException;
import org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRuleHelper;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.apache.maven.execution.RuntimeInformation;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.expression.ExpressionEvaluationException;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException;

/**
 * Custom rules to enforce for maven dependencies
 *
 */
public class CustomRule implements EnforcerRule
{
    /**
     * Simple param. This rule will fail if the value is true.
     */
    private boolean shouldIfail = false;

    public void execute( EnforcerRuleHelper helper )
        throws EnforcerRuleException
    {
        Log log = helper.getLog();

        try
        {
            // get the various expressions out of the helper.
            MavenProject project = (MavenProject) helper.evaluate( "${project}" );
            MavenSession session = (MavenSession) helper.evaluate( "${session}" );
            String target = (String) helper.evaluate( "${project.build.directory}" );
            String artifactId = (String) helper.evaluate( "${project.artifactId}" );
            String version = (String) helper.evaluate( "${project.version}" );

            if(version != null && version.length() > 7 && version.substring(0, 7).equals("master-")) {
                this.shouldIfail = true;
            }

            // retreive any component out of the session directly
            ArtifactResolver resolver = (ArtifactResolver) helper.getComponent( ArtifactResolver.class );
            RuntimeInformation rti = (RuntimeInformation) helper.getComponent( RuntimeInformation.class );

            log.info( "Retrieved Target Folder: " + target );
            log.info( "Retrieved ArtifactId: " +artifactId );
            log.info( "Retrieved Project: " + project );
            log.info( "Retrieved RuntimeInfo: " + rti );
            log.info( "Retrieved Session: " + session );
            log.info( "Retrieved Resolver: " + resolver );

            if ( this.shouldIfail )
            {
                throw new EnforcerRuleException( "Failing because my param said so." );
            }
        }
        catch ( ComponentLookupException e )
        {
            throw new EnforcerRuleException( "Unable to lookup a component " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e );
        }
        catch ( ExpressionEvaluationException e )
        {
            throw new EnforcerRuleException( "Unable to lookup an expression " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e );
        }
    }


    public String getCacheId()
    {
        //no hash on boolean...only parameter so no hash is needed.
        return ""+this.shouldIfail;
    }


    public boolean isCacheable()
    {
        return false;
    }


    public boolean isResultValid( EnforcerRule arg0 )
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But that class only checks for project version. I want to get dependencies versions as well. How to get all the versions to check if they start from "master-" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the artefacts via

```
MavenProject project = (MavenProject) helper.evaluate("${project}");
Set<Artifact> artifacts = project.getArtifacts();
```

And check for the artefacts with certain group id by:

```
boolean containsInvalid = artifacts.stream()
.filter(item -> item.getGroupId()
.startsWith("master-"))
.anyMatch(item -> isInvalid(item));
```

`isInvalid()` would be your own implementation.

Comment: I want to check if all the project versions and dependency versions start from "master-". You are checking for project groupIds and dependency groupIds. I think you just replace `item.getGroupId()` with `item.getVersion()` ?

Comment: My mistake, I thought you had the "master-" as groupId. Yes, you can use `getVersion()` or `getBaseVersion()`, whatever suits your needs best.

Comment: ok that seems reasonable. Also this code is in a module named 'customRule' whose parent project is 'tools'. Now if I add the dependency of 'customRule' module in 'tools' main project and adding execution as `<execution><id>enforce-no-master-versions</id>  <goals><goal>enforce</goal></goals> <configuration><skip>true</skip> <rules><message>No Master Versions Allowed!</message</rules> </configuration></execution>` then I am getting error: `Cannot create instance of interface org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRule: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRule.<init>()`.

Comment: You need to cite your implementation class, see https://maven.apache.org/enforce under 5)

Comment: So that implementation hint will go in child module’s pom or parent project pom? Custom rule class is in child module so putting implementation hint in parent is not applicable. Right?

Comment: Pls check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315914/enforce-custom-rule-in-parent-project