# enforce custom rule in external projects

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have one Parent maven project and 4 modules in that project:

[image]

Now I want to put some custom rule that says there can be no project versions or dependency versions that begin with the string "master-". This rule will be applicable to all the external projects that depends on eBill Software.

So I created a new module with name customRule whose parent is again eBill Software. I followed [writing-a-custom-rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) and my rule class is in new module.

Relevant part of CustomRule.java in module customRule:

```
 MavenProject project = (MavenProject) helper.evaluate( "${project}" );
 Set<Artifact> artifacts = project.getArtifacts();

            boolean containsInvalid = artifacts.stream()
                    .filter(item -> item.getVersion()
                    .startsWith("master-"))
                    .anyMatch(item -> true);

            if(containsInvalid) {
                this.shouldIfail = true;
            }
```

Relevant part of customRule module pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-no-master-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <myCustomRule implementation="org.apache.customRule.CustomRule">
                                    <shouldIfail>false</shouldIfail>
                                </myCustomRule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now I want to access this custom rule in parent module eBill Software:

So what should I enter in its pom.xml and external project's pom.xml to be able to get the custom rule applicable to all the external projects that depends on eBill Software.

Comment: If I correctly understand you need to configure maven-enforcer-plugin including your custom rule into the eBill pom...

Comment: @khmarbaise - that’s correct.

Comment: @khmarbaise- I also have a second problem which is elaborated here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338179/maven-custom-rule-failing-or-passing-without-considering-custom-rule