# maven custom rule failing or passing without considering custom rule

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am following [writing-a-custom-rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) document to create custom rule and applying it.

My enforcer plugin execution has the following entry in pom.xml file-

```
<execution>
            <id>enforce-no-masters</id>
            <configuration>
              <skip>${masterDependenciesAllowed}</skip>
                <rules>
                   <myCustomRule implementation="or.apache.customRule.CustomRule">
                      <excludes>
                       <exclude>*:*:master-*:*:*</exclude>
                      </excludes>
                       <shouldIfail>false</shouldIfail>
                   </myCustomRule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
```

The issue is if I keep `<shouldIfail>true</shouldIfail>` then I always get failure and if I keep `<shouldIfail>false</shouldIfail>` then I always get success.

so I don't know that how to put value of java class variable `shouldIfail` in the tag so that it will be dynamically pass or fail based on logic.

Comment: This parameter `shouldIfail` is defined in the custom rule as an example.I would recommend to remove it first...and also take a look into maven-enforcer-rules how to write tests for such rules...

Comment: I am using this parameter `shouldIfail` in my custom rule class. So if I remove it from `pom.xml` then will it pass/fail based on `shouldIfail` value in my custom rule class? I have created my class by following `Writing a custom rule` document given in maven documentation.

Comment: I got it working by removing shouldIfail from pom. Thanks!